# Error al generar un Excel con el paquete xlsx

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando generar un Excel usando el paquete xlsx y el problema es que el Excel se genera vacío a pesar de que le paso el arreglo donde tengo la información, el cual tiene la siguiente forma
datos = [dato1,dato2,dato3]

Comment: Hola, ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de código con el que estas trabajando? Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga mejor aceptación

Comment: gracias, ya lo solucione. Voy a tratar de escribir mejor la próxima vez que necesite ayuda